# C# Server side for android app client

Tags: c#, android, .net, client-server

I creating an android app (client side) , and I'm not sure on which technology should I need to use for the server side.
The Server must be in C#.

information about the client: the client should be able to send a files to the server for analyze and the server will send the analyze result to the client.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ASP.NET WEB Api. I will not be more precise just have a look on google about that, you will find all the needed informations